# vba searching through rows and their associated columns and highlight if conditions meet

Tags: vba, search, row, highlight

The code below would search through a row and its associated columns.
For Row 7, if it is a "N" or "TR" and if all entries are blank below line 12,the code would hide the entire column.

However, I still need help with some further help!

1. If there is a "N" or "TR" in row 7. If there **is** something writen in any cell, (rather than leaving it alone), can I highlight its associated cell in row 7 in yellow?
2. If ther eis a "Y" in row 7, If there is any **empty** cells, can I highlight its associated cell in row 7 in yellow?

Thank you so much! special thanks to KazJaw for my previous post about simular issue

```
Sub checkandhide()

Dim r As Range

Dim Cell As Range

Set r = Range("A7", Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

For Each Cell In r

    If Cell.Value = "N" Or Cell.Value = "TR" Then
        If Cells(Rows.Count, Cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row < 13 Then
            Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[attached example of spreadsheet](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-mbWxnUGYXQ8/UdTP5k_XBtI/AAAAAAAAAA8/wSQW-PG043o/s872/help.png)

Comment: Your description is quite unclear. Please, take a look at my code and at my explanations and let me know if I got properly what you meant.

Comment: @Brian, could you clarify point 2nd, any empty cell below is possible if you consider all 1.000.000 rows in Excel. So, where is the bottom limit within we should search for empty cells?

Comment: @KazJaw, @ varocarbas, Sorry for unclear question. "attached example of spreadsheet" below my code shows an example. I would like to make the code as generic as possible. So, Whatever the user feeds into the code, I would like it to check through the rows all the way until the very last entered cell (referenced with column A). For example. Column A (Animal ID Reference) has 40 rows of ID names. I would like to make sure that every other columns with "Y" in row 7 does not have empty entries from its cell 13 all the way down to the end (which is 40 in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an improved version of your code (although I might need further clarifications... read below).

```
Sub checkandhide()

    Dim r as Range, Cell As Range, curRange As Range

    Set r = Range("A7", Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

    For Each Cell In r

        Set curRange = Range(Cells(13, Cell.Column), Cells(Rows.Count, Cell.Column)) 'Range from row 13 until last row in the given column
        If Cell.Value = "N" Or Cell.Value = "TR" Then
            If Application.CountBlank(curRange) = curRange.Cells.Count Then
                Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm
            End If
        ElseIf Cell.Value = "Y" Then
            If Application.CountBlank(curRange) > 0 Then
                 Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I am not sure if I have understood your instructions properly and thus I will describe here what this code does exactly; please, comment any issue which is not exactly as you want and such that I can update the code accordingly:

It looks for all the cells in range `r`.

- If the given cell (which might be in row 7 or in any other row below it) meets one of the conditions, the corresponding actions would be performed.
- Part of the conditions depends on `curRange`, which is defined as all the rows between row number 13 until the end of the spreadsheet.
- Specific conditions:
  a) If the value of the current cell is N or TR. If all the cells in `curRange` are blank, the current column is hidden. If there is, at least, a non-blank cell, the background color of the given cell would be set to yellow.
  b) If the value of the current cell is Y and there is, at least, one cell in `curRange` which is not blank, the background color of the background cell would be set to yellow.

Comment: @vacrocarbas, Thank you very much varocarbas! The code did a great job, but the specific condition b) does not seem to work well. The code highlighted the cells with "Y" even if there are no blanks in the curRange. I wonder did the code count more than the set range curRange?

Comment: As you can read in my description, this is what it is supposed to be doing: when Y is typed, the background is set to yellow if there is, at least, one cell NOT being blank (= there are no blanks). In any case, I guess that you can work on my code, understand each single bit and adapt it to your specific needs.

Comment: @vacrocarbas, Thank you once again! I did look at it carefully and made some corresponding edits. It worked great!

Comment: No problem. By the way, my nick is varocarbas :)

Comment: btw, I still have one more question. The coding you wrote includes all the cells below the column, right? Can I restright the row count to an exact value since it would not work for "Y" as cells are all blank below the usedrage.

Comment: Ah! you meant curRange? Yes. You can edit it to account just for the number of rows in r (r.Rows.Count) or for the rows in any other range (any_range.Rows.Count). As said, I wasn't sure about your exact requirements and have just written a code to provide a general insight, which I expected you to change/adapt.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not having much knowledge at vba. I had actually never learned to program, but was forced to seek help for this project. Let me post a new question as I wish to add some specific feature in the vba. I am looking to set range limited to the used cells in column A under row 13

Comment: You don't have to apologise because of not having knowledge; just intend to acquire it. First thing you should do is understanding what makes exactly the code I have delivered: it goes through all the cells in range r; creates a secondary range (curRange) including all the rows in the given column of the cell currently being analysed from row 13 until the last row (you can edit the value of the last row by changing the Rows.Count part); the conditions (having blank cells/not) are applied to curRange (from 13 until last row) and the background being change belongs to the current cell (Cell)

Comment: Please, put my last paragraph and the code together (+ some research if needed) to understand what is going on on this code; what needs to be improved/extended. If you want to learn to program, you would have to start doing things by your own; if you don't want to learn, you should hire a programmer to do it for you; but I don't think that keep asking and asking is the most adequate thing and much less here: this is a forum for programmers and thus the answers are expected to be taken as a small help to allow you to grow as a programmers. If you are not a programmer you shouldn't be here.

Comment: ahh. Thanks for the clear description on the code. You have been helping a lot.I can now understand the meaning of the code way better! :). So for the Rows.Count (which means the number of rows the coding will search through). What should I replace it with if I would like to search and stop until the last cell which is occupied in column A (the column A is the referencing column). Do I need to set another range for reference or change (Rows.Count) into something like "A:A".End(xlDown)? I cannot write down the exact number since the file is generic for other workbooks containing different rows.

Comment: Rows.Count refers to the maximum number of rows in the current worksheet; that is, in the range defining the current worksheet. Rows.Count is associated to any range. Please, read my previous comment: you do need to improve your knowledge quite a lot and I don't think that I am (or this site in the way you are using it)  the best person for doing it. Take the code as it is; or spend some time understanding it/doing some research to edit it; or hire someone to edit it for you. But I hope that you will understand that I will stop answering your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will do more research and work on my knowledge.