# Scan each gridview row in each column and hide the column if all rows are empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview something like this. It is binded in a datasource. Now, what I need is to hide the columns that its rows has no data available. In the table example below, the column with "2ND" as HeaderText should be hidden since it has no data.

[image]

```
Protected Sub grdsf_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles grdsf.DataBound
        Dim rowscount As Integer = grdsf.Rows.Count
        Dim columnscount As Integer = grdsf.Columns.Count
        Dim k As Integer = 0
        For j As Integer = 1 To columnscount - 1 Step j + 1
            For i As Integer = 0 To rowscount - 1 step i + 1
                Dim x As String = grdsf.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text
                If x = String.Empty Then
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            Next
            Dim col As DataControlField = grdsf.Columns(j)
            If k = rowscount Then
                col.Visible = False
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
```

*The loop for column starts at index 1 since the 1st column should not be hidden..*

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdsf" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="Horizontal" ShowFooter="True" Width="90%">
<RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LNAME" HeaderText="LNAME" SortExpression="LNAME" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="OYRGR" HeaderText="OYRGR" SortExpression="OYRGR" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Swimming" HeaderText="Swimming" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Swimming" NullDisplayText="" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Soccer" HeaderText="Soccer" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Soccer" NullDisplayText="" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Softball" HeaderText="Softball" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Softball" NullDisplayText="" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Baseball" HeaderText="Baseball" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Baseball" NullDisplayText="" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Volleyball" HeaderText="Volleyball" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Volleyball" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Basketball" HeaderText="Basketball" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Basketball" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Martial Arts" HeaderText="Martial Arts" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Martial Arts" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Karate" HeaderText="Karate" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Karate" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Arnis" HeaderText="Arnis" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Arnis" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Taekwondo" HeaderText="Taekwondo" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Taekwondo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Judo" HeaderText="Judo" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Judo" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Boxing" HeaderText="Boxing" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Boxing" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Wrestling" HeaderText="Wrestling" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Wrestling" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Unit Physical Fitness" HeaderText="Unit Physical Fitness" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Unit Physical Fitness" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Gymnastics" HeaderText="Gymnastics" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Gymnastics" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Health and Fitness" HeaderText="Health and Fitness" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Health and Fitness" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Sports Mngt." HeaderText="Sports Mngt." ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Sports Mngt." />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Badminton" HeaderText="Badminton" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Badminton" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: so lets just say.. in your gridview you have 3 rows then 5 columns. All rows and columns has value except in 2nd row and 3rd column. so meaning you need to remove that 3rd column although 1,2,4,5 columns has value?

Comment: @Unknownymous I put an example above :)

Comment: yes.. i will update my answer...

Comment: @eirishainjel what will happen when u have alternate data? like 1 row has empty and one don't have then?

Comment: @Justcode - If all the rows in a column are empty, then that column shall be hidden. Thus, if there is even one data available in a column, it should not be hidden.

Comment: @eirishainjel check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17485746/2630817

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this method.

```
Private Sub HideBlankColumns()
    Dim bHasValue As Boolean
    Dim sValue As String
    For iCol As Integer = 0 To GridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        bHasValue = False
        For iRow As Integer = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
            sValue = (GridView1.Rows(iRow).FindControl("LableID") As Label).Text
            If GridView1.Rows(iRow).Cells(iCol).Text != String.Empty && sValue != String.Empty Then
                bHasValue = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'To Hide the column
        If bHasValue = False Then
            GridView1.Columns(iCol).Visible = False
        End If

        ' ''To Remove the Column
        ''If bHasValue = False Then
        ''    GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(iCol)
        ''    iCol -= 1
        ''End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this part: `If GridView1.Item(iCol, iRow).Value IsNot Nothing Then`. I used your code and edit it like this `If grdsf.Rows(iRow).Cells(iCol).Text <> String.Empty Then
                grdsf.Columns(iCol).Visible = True
                ElseIf grdsf.Rows(iRow).Cells(iCol).Text = String.Empty Then
                grdsf.Columns(iCol).Visible = False
                End If` but it isn't working.

Comment: Becoze the `GridView1.Item(iCol, iRow).Value` type is not defined. So, it may be integer, string, boolean or any. either `GridView1.Item(iCol, iRow).Value` can be `Nothing` or `DBNull.Value`.
try `DBNull.Value` instead of `Nothing`.

Comment: `'Item'` is not a member of `System.Web.Ui.WebControls.GridView`

Comment: ohh, sorry i just forgot it. It won't work if there is a `TemplateColumn`. in that case you have to fetch value like this `(grdsf.Rows(iRow).FindControl("lableid") as Label).Text`.

Comment: @eirishainjel its looks ok to me now what u have problem now?

Comment: `Dim x As Integer = grdsf.Rows.Count
        Dim b As Integer = grdsf.Columns.Count
        For j As Integer = 1 To b - 1
            Dim k As Integer
            For i As Integer = 0 To x - 1
                Dim x As String = grdsf.Rows(i).Cells(j).Text
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ToString) Then
                    k = k + 1
                End If
            Next
            If k = x Then
                grdsf.Columns(j).Visible = False
            Else
                grdsf.Columns(j).Visible = True
            End If
        Next`

Comment: My `GridView` has no `TemplateColumn`. I have a code (above) that I am trying and I think it is close to what I want but unfortunately is not working. I am holding the logic of this code. The loop for column starts on index 1 since index 0 should not remain.

Comment: there are some problem in your code. for example there are duplicate declaration taken for `x` variable. I think you should try different method. How do you bind the GridView?

Comment: Can we talk in chat room. So, other developer can also give better suggestion.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net

Comment: @eirishainjel but its updated why don't u do this way?

Comment: @Wulworine - I'm sorry.. I only have 9 reputations. Can't do the chat :) toldya, I'm not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
For each _Row as GridViewRow in Gridview1.rows
    For each _Col as GridViewColumn in Gridview1.columns

    If Gridview1.rows(_row.index).item(_col.index).value = Nothing Then

          GRidView1.Columns.remove(_col.index) 

    End If

Next
```